# Ruby/Rails Explicit/Implicit constant call from inside a model. Benchmark/Performance doubts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a doubt regarding the use of constants defined and used inside the same class

```
class Car
  CON = "xxx"
  def some_method    
    puts CON
    puts Car::CON    
  end       
end
```

Will accessing `CON` by just writing `CON` improve the performance instead of `Car::CON`. I know it's a good practice to just access it via `CON` if its defined in the same class, but I had a doubt if it also improves the performance.

Also, if we look in Rails, would using

```
Car.where(...)
```

cause any performance issues instead of just using

```
where(...)
```

from inside the `Car` model.

Thanks

Comment: I have never seen `P::CON`. Did you mean `Car::CON` ?

Comment: That must have been a typo. I edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I see no difference here.  `Car.where` and `where` is just explicit and implicit call of the same method. There are 2 variants because of the scopes(`public`/`private`/`protected`)  and you can call `private` methods only implicitly.

About constants, I've just checked and here are results(sometimes it shows more for 1 call, sometimes for 2 call, but they are near the same every time):

```
require 'benchmark'

class Car
  CON = "xxx"

  def some_method
    Benchmark.bm do |x|
      x.report { CON }
      x.report { Car::CON }
    end
  end
end

Car.new.some_method

       user     system      total        real
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000013)
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000013)
```

So for both questions the answer is the same: there is no difference in performance.

Comment: What is your version of ruby and system specs ?

Comment: @dknight I have multiple Ruby versions on my laptop, it makes no difference, I tested this on 1.9.3 and 2.2.0 and received same result.

Comment: @rustam-a-gasanov Can you try Shivam's code and see there is any difference ? I do not know the internals of Benchmark but we could try and see.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did to verify this:

test.rb

```
require 'benchmark'
class Car
  CON = "xxx"
  def self.some_method
    time1 = Benchmark.measure do
      puts CON
    end
    time2 = Benchmark.measure do
      puts Car::CON
    end
    puts "Time1"
    puts time1
    puts "Time2"
    puts time2
  end
  Car::some_method
end
```

Output:

```
xxx
xxx
Time1
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000078)
Time2
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000025)
```

Looks `Car::CON` is faster than `CON`. But just to be sure I swap their position in the code. (i.e Time1 is now for `Car::CON` and Time2 for `CON`)

Output:

```
xxx
xxx
Time1
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000051)
Time2
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000022)
```

As you can see it always takes more time to load the constants on first time. Therefore we cannot come to any conclusion. Also output 2 seems to suggest `Car::CON` is still faster, but if you run the scrip a couple of times, you will know you cannot say that for sure.

My suggestion would be to use `Car::CON` as its more readable compared to `CON`. Also `Car::CON` can be used to access the constant from outside, making it more standard.

Also in my model I did:

```
  def self.test_method
    time1 = Benchmark.measure do
      where(:user_id => 1)
    end
    time2 = Benchmark.measure do
      self.where(:user_id => 1)
    end
    puts "Time1"
    puts time1
    puts "Time2"
    puts time2
  end
```

Output #1:

```
Time1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000450)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Time2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000182)
```

Output #2 (after swapping `where` and `self.where` ):

```
Time1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000348)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Time2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000187)
```

Again showing the same result. Meaning they are both same performance wise.

In this case too I will suggest use `self.where` as its more readable.

Comment: This is caching. They are the same. Swap `where(:user_id => 1)` and `self.where(:user_id => 1)` and you will see opposite results

Comment: @RustamA.Gasanov I accidentally ignored that in my first answer. But I have already edited my answer. Please check.